# Cancel Live Agent chats going to a particular queue

Tags: liveagent, omnichannel

In our org, we have live chats going to specific queues based on certain criteria. If a chat doesn't meet any criteria, it's currently getting assigned to a queue that no agents will be picking chats up from. Let's call this queue dead_end_queue.

The problem is that any chats that get assigned to dead-end-queue, the user keeps seeing a message that says "Your position in the queue is 1. Please wait for the next available agent"

Instead of this message, I just want to cancel the chat and display a message that says "We are unable to connect you to an agent at this time."

How can I go about this?